# How to clone an object from PHP extension

Tags: c, clone, php-extension

I am trying to implement the prototype design pattern in my extension. How can I clone an object from an `zval*`. Is there a zend function equivalent to the userland `clone` operator?

**Update**

I wrote the following function for cloning an object. Not sure if there is a better way.

```
/**
 * Clones an object from src to dest
 */
static int php_custom_clone(zval *src, zval *dest TSRMLS_DC) {
    zend_class_entry *ce;
    zend_object_clone_obj_t clone_call;

    ce = Z_OBJCE_P(src);
    clone_call =  Z_OBJ_HT_P(src)->clone_obj;

    if (!clone_call) {
        if (ce) {
            zend_throw_exception_ex(Custom_Exception_ce_ptr, 0 TSRMLS_CC, "Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class %s", ce->name);
        } else {
            zend_throw_exception_ex(Custom_Exception_ce_ptr, 0 TSRMLS_CC, "Trying to clone an uncloneable object");
        }
    } else {
        if (!EG(exception)) {
            Z_OBJVAL_P(dest) = clone_call(src TSRMLS_CC);
            Z_TYPE_P(dest) = IS_OBJECT;
            Z_SET_REFCOUNT_P(dest, 1);
            // Z_SET_ISREF_P(dest);
            if (EG(exception)) {
                zval_ptr_dtor(&dest);
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generic clone method...

```
zend_object_value val =  zend_objects_clone_obj(zval *zobject TSRMLS_DC);
```

Comment: Thank you. Does `zend_objects_clone_obj` clone both the custom object storage and the object properties?

Comment: yea, it does.   If you want more examples then check any ext*  code.  for example:   dbstmt_clone_obj()  method in  ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c

Comment: This does not seem to copy non-default object properties as of PHP 7.4

Comment: As reported by SOFe earlier, this only copies default properties

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f3c9597bc2a0ef9618623803fa9a83e213ccb154/Zend/zend_objects.c#L255